# Generate in CMake header-only library that "stores" its dependency on boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, linker, cmake

I want to generate in cmake a header-only library from `header.h`, that depends on libboost_system.
I can compile the library without problems with:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
        system filesystem
        REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_library(mylib header.h)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

But when I link to mylib elsewhere, it fails finding the boost library with a ld error.

The failure makes sense, but I don't know how to solve it in CMake.
How do I "store" the boost dependency on mylib? So I don't have to worry about finding the boost library in other external project?

EDIT: I am using cmake 3.2

UPDATE: mylib is a SHARED lib (.so), when I use it in other project, the linker is not able to find the boost library:

`target_link_libraries(newproject.exe ${external_mylib})`

```
undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/PATH/TO/libboost_system-mt-d.so.1.57.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is solved if I explicitly link again to the Boost_LIBRARIES.
`target_link_libraries(newproject.exe ${external_mylib} ${Boost_LIBRARIES))`

This doesn't avoid finding again the boost_libraries, maybe the solution is to put the boost_libraries in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH?
That would be an overkill...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CMake version to 2.8.12 or newer.

The feature you are looking for is [transitive dependency handling](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/policy/CMP0022.html#policy:CMP0022). It is toggled by the CMake policy `CMP0022`, so make sure you do not accidentally switch that off somewhere. Quoting from the [manpage for `target_link_libraries` in CMake 3.1](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_link_libraries.html):

> Library dependencies are transitive by default with this signature.
>   When this target is linked into another target then the libraries
>   linked to this target will appear on the link line for the other
>   target too. This transitive “link interface” is stored in the
>   INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES target property and may be overridden by
>   setting the property directly. When CMP0022 is not set to NEW,
>   transitive linking is built in but may be overridden by the
>   LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES property. Calls to other signatures of this
>   command may set the property making any libraries linked exclusively
>   by this signature private.

Btw, [Boost.System](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) is not the same as [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). Make sure you actually link to the correct library.

From your edit it seems that you are dealing with two separate CMake projects, which means you have to carry the dependency chain of `mylib` over to the other project. Take a look at [CMake's packaging mechanism](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) for how to do that.

Comment: I have tried with: `target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC and INTERFACE ${Boost_Libraries))`
But no luck.

Because I am not linking that library to any executable, I wonder if cmake properly builds it, of I have to add explicit requirements for BUILD and INSTALL.

Thanks pointing the filesystem, I am using both in my project, but chopped it out here for simplicity, and because I am getting the linking error from system. I have cmake 3.2

Comment: @phcerdan What kind of library are you building? Note that these dependencies are only resolved by the linker, *not* by the librarian, so if you build a static lib, nothing will get linked. Always be sure to carry the full dependency chain to the linker, that is, the point where you build a dll or an executable.

Comment: I have set the policy, even though I am using a modern cmake. Check my update if you wish, I am building a shared lib.

Comment: From your edit it seems that you are dealing with two separate CMake projects, which means you have to carry the dependency chain of `mylib` over to the other project. Take a look at [CMake's packaging mechanism](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) for how to do that. Also note that it is still quite hard to see from your question what your actual setup looks like. Consider building a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting questions like this in the future.

Comment: @phcerdan From your edit it seems that you are dealing with two separate CMake projects, which means you have to carry the dependency chain of `mylib` over to the other project. Take a look at [CMake's packaging mechanism](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) for how to do that. Also note that it is still quite hard to see from your question what your actual setup looks like. Consider building a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting questions like this in the future.